# Best way to solve Python data structure problem...is a heap necessary here?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I'm working on a Data Structures and Algorithm problem that I can't seem to solve. The problem is:

Given a list of [FileName, FileSize, [Collection]] with Collection being optional, code a system that 1) calculates total size of files processed and 2) calculate top K collections based on size.  A collection can have 1 or more files. Also, the same file can be a part of more than one collection.

Example Input:

```
K = 2
file1.txt(size: 100)
file2.txt(size: 200) in collection "collection1"
file3.txt(size: 200) in collection "collection1"
file4.txt(size: 300) in collection "collection2"
file5.txt(size: 100)
file6.txt(size: 200) in collection "collection1" and "collection3"
```

Expected Output:

```
Total size of files processed: 1100
Top 2 collections:
-collection1: 600
-collection2: 300
```

I feel like a priority queue/heap might be a possible solution but I'm not sure the best way to implement. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If K is small you could get away with insertion into a sorted fixed size array. The advantage being that you don't have to store N items (like you would in a heap) and thus use less RAM.

In the real world it's not just CPU cycles you care about but RAM space as well.

Inserting would take O(logK) to find the right spot and then you'd need to copy over the elements to make space (and discard any elements more than k).  So it would be faster in terms of comparisons than a single removal from a heap or an insertion into a heapified structure.

Comment: Just use `Counter.most_common`.